# Kohana 3.3 How to get a files into array?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

For example I have a files in my views directory:

```
views/admin/store/test1.php
views/admin/store/test2.php
views/admin/store/test3.php
```

How to get them into array?

Comment: you want the file content? needs a little more info here. Do you want to scan a folder for files and get the file names or content or someting like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$views = Kohana::list_files('views/admin/store');
```

This will get all the files inside this folder in the cascading filesystem, by checking modules etc too..

Comment: basename will get you there :)

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution:

```
$fileArray = array();

$directory = APPPATH . 'views/admin/store/*';

foreach ( glob($directory) as $filename ) {
    $result = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    array_push($fileArray, $result);
}
```

Some note:
with

```
'views/templates/*'
```

you'll find all the files in the directory. you could also 'filter' the results this way:

```
'views/templates/*.php'
```

the contant PATHINFO_BASENAME returns only the filename, for other information you can use PATHINFO_DIRNAME, PATHINFO_EXTENSION or PATHINFO_FILENAME. (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php )